# Redirect stderr within script and add prefix

Tags: linux, bash, redirect, sed

I am trying to redirect the stderr output to a file from within the script in bash, and for each error output that is written, I want to add a prefix containing the current script name and the timestamp. This is the way I am doing it:

```
exec 2> >(sed "s/^/\n$(date +'%Y%m%d%H%M%S') - JOB: $(basename $BASH_SOURCE)\n\n/" >&2) 2>> file.log
echo This goes to stderr >&2
```

I used the information from [this](https://superuser.com/questions/882019/linux-shell-how-to-add-prefix-string-to-stderr-message) other post, and there the last redirection is `>> file.log` instead of `2>> file.log`, but if I do it like this, then I get the stderr on the console (the prefix is also added), and the stdout in the file.

So that is why I added the `2` in `2>> file.log` since the sed replacement is also outputted to stderr, so this way the redirection works correctly, but the prefix is not added. So instead of getting:

```
20170729100156 - JOB: script.sh

This goes to stderr
```

I only get:

```
This goes to stderr
```

Can anyone recommend a solution, or why this is happening? Thanks.

Comment: Can you not redirect the error to a temporary file then take the output from the temporary file, add the required date and script path data and then append it to the main error file?

Comment: Thanks, but to be honest, doesn't seem like a good solution. Besides, what I posted should be working, but I don't understand what I'm missing.

Comment: This technique is new to me, but I suspect that the reason your code fails is that the `>> file.log` or `2>> file.log` redirects the output of the `echo`, not the output of the `sed...` process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not directly redirect the output of `sed` directly to the log file?

```
exec 2> >(sed "s/^/\n$(date +'%Y%m%d%H%M%S') - JOB: $(basename $BASH_SOURCE)\n\n/" >> file.log)
echo This goes to stderr >&2
```